# Ruby HTML attributes to Hash or Array

Tags: html, ruby, string, parsing, hash

type="checkbox" name="prdCdList" value="102001174" class="bnone" newfl="Y" cpnfl="N" catcpnfl="N" eventfl="N" catcd1="102000" catcd2="102001" prdimgl="/upload/product/320_1405497216907.jpg" prdnm="Dear my volume" prdvol="3.4g" prdlndesc="Limited Pink" selprc="10000" spsalprc="0" cpnprc="0" cashptrat="0" cashpt="0" discpt="0" salstatcdnm="Available" salstatcd="PS01" prdwidth="0" prdheight="0" prddepth="0" pricestr="" price="10000" prepromote="" endpromote=""

---

I am currently using bunch of regexes to parse above data into a structured array or hash.
Actual tag includes much more values. Thought there must be a better way in Ruby like using split or something? There are spaces between attributes but also within certain values so..

Can any one suggest a good way to handle this type of string?

I would like the result be:

```
hash = { 
 type => "checkbox",
 name => "prdCdList",
... so on.
}
```

or

```
arr = [
 "checkbox",
 "prdCdList",
... so on.
]
```

Would appreciate any advice =]

Thanks,

Comment: have you tried http://nokogiri.org?

Comment: @UriAgassi Yep am using it. If you can let me know how I would be able to parse just the values with Nokogiri that would be great! They are inside one tag, so if I select that tag with xpath or CSS, it would return the whole tag. I am currently doing that + regex to get the inside values..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Nokogiri, the attributes are already parsed for you - simply access them using [`[]`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse('<html><body><div type="checkbox" name="prdCdList" value="102001174" class="bnone" newfl="Y" cpnfl="N" catcpnfl="N" eventfl="N" catcd1="102000" catcd2="102001" prdimgl="/upload/product/320_1405497216907.jpg" prdnm="Dear my volume" prdvol="3.4g" prdlndesc="Limited Pink" selprc="10000" spsalprc="0" cpnprc="0" cashptrat="0" cashpt="0" discpt="0" salstatcdnm="Available" salstatcd="PS01" prdwidth="0" prdheight="0" prddepth="0" pricestr="" price="10000" prepromote="" endpromote=""></body></html>')
div = doc.css('div').first
div['prdnm']
# => "Dear my volume"
```

From the [documentation](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html):

> `Nokogiri::XML::Node` is your window to the fun filled world of dealing
>   with XML and HTML tags. A `Nokogiri::XML::Node` may be treated similarly
>   to a hash with regard to attributes. For example (from irb):
>
> ```
> 01.irb(main):004:0> node
> 02.=> <a href="#foo" id="link">link</a>
> 03.irb(main):005:0> node['href']
> 04.=> "#foo"
> 05.irb(main):006:0> node.keys
> 06.=> ["href", "id"]
> 07.irb(main):007:0> node.values
> 08.=> ["#foo", "link"]
> 09.irb(main):008:0> node['class'] = 'green'
> 10.=> "green"
> 11.irb(main):009:0> node
> 12.=> <a href="#foo" id="link" class="green">link</a>
> 13.irb(main):010:0>
> ```
>
> See `Nokogiri::XML::Node#[]` and `Nokogiri::XML#[]=` for more information.

Comment: wow...that was so simple and neat.. thank you so much. That seems to be such a basic feature of Nokogiri.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
node.attributes.each_with_object({}) {|(k,v), acc| acc[k] = v.value }
```

where `node` is your tag.